# Am facing following issue while working with openSSL

Tags: java, openssl

Am facing following issue while working with openSSL.

### Below are the server details:

```
Tomcat : 8.5.43
Ubuntu: 18. 
JVM: 1.8.0_221-b11 
Apache Tomcat Native library: 1.2.23 
APR Version: 1.7.0 
Open SSL : 1.1.1
```

### Below is our Connector configuration:

```
<Connector port="8443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
    maxThreads="150" 
    minSpareThreads="25"
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true" 
    SSLEnabled="true"
    acceptCount="100" 
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    SSLCertificateFile="certificate/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="certificate/servercertkey.pem"
    SSLVerifyClient="optional" 
    SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
    SSLCipherSuite="RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5">
</Connector>
```

### Am getting following error:

```
29-Jul-2019 12:56:48.856 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.<clinit> Failed getting cipher list
    java.lang.Exception: Not implemented
            at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.newSSL(Native Method)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.<clinit>(OpenSSLEngine.java:77)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getImplementedProtocols(OpenSSLUtil.java:54)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:92)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:82)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.<init>(OpenSSLUtil.java:42)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.createSSLContext(AprEndpoint.java:397)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:368)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1118)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

29-Jul-2019 12:56:48.941 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers The certificate [certificate/server.crt] or its private key [certificate/servercertkey.pem] could not be processed using a JSSE key manager and will be given directly to OpenSSL
29-Jul-2019 12:56:48.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1037 ms
```

---

What am doing wrong? Any pointers would help.

Thank you in advance.